# How To Send Cash To BTC-e, Crypto-Trade

Tags: sending, cash

I have bee scouring on how to fund accounts in captioned exchanges from the US-preferably with a credit card or even paypal where possible, I suppose no online sites would do ACH confirmations type transactions. I have noticed some of online sites don't want to deal with us on this side of the pond. What ways are some you using to fund your accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Most exchanges which support USD exchange will be funded via international wire. Depending on your bank these charges can be between 10-50USD.

If your transferring from a different currency the rate given on conversion is better than if you were to purchase USD in cash from your high street but lower than spot on forex markets.

ACH / domestic transfers will come when domestic (to you) exchanges build more solid relationships with banks when more regulation comes in place.

Trading with locally on places like localbitcoins is the best bet if the percentage in fees is larger than 5% of the amount you plan to buy. This is a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score -1):

Don't send cash to BTC-e.com. They're horrible and are having serious issues with fiat transfers. I recommend only moving coins in and out of btc-e.com.

My personal favorite is using localbitcoins.com to buy coins in cash. Send those bitcoins to your btc-e.com and trade away! In the past, I have also used Dwolla/MtGox as a way of transfering fiat from my US bank account into bitcoins. Good luck!